# Best practice for updating TextBlock content dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm doing a WPF application with a *UserControl* with a *TextBlock* element. The content of this elements depends on an enum in the view model (Success, Pending, Error etc.).

Here are some example of the different states the TextBlock:

**Example 1 - Simple**

```
<TextBlock>
  Please wait
</TextBlock>
```

**Example 2 - With hyperlink**

```
<TextBlock>
  Searching for item. <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DetailsCommand}">Link to details</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

**Example 3 - With linebreak**

```
<TextBlock>
  The content has been uploaded<LineBreak />
  The item is not ready to use
</TextBlock>
```

What is the best approach for changing the content of this element dynamically depending on the state of my enum in the view model? If I bind the Text property to a string in my view model, I don't think that I'm able to insert child elements like *Hyperlink*, *LineBreak* etc. What options do I have?

Comment: There was a neat custom control I wrote a long time ago, the `ConditionalPresenter`, I should create a Nuget package with that or something....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement it with TemplateSelector:

```
public class TemplSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    var element = container as FrameworkElement;

    if (element != null && item != null)
    {
        var vm = (ViewModel)item;

        if (vm.YourEnum == 1)
            return element.FindResource("templ1") as DataTemplate;
        else if (vm.YourEnum == 0)
            return element.FindResource("templ0") as DataTemplate;
    }

    return null;
}
}
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TemplSelector x:Key="templSel"/>        
</Window.Resources>
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templSel}" Content="{Binding ViewModel}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="templ0">
            <TextBlock>
                Please wait
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="templ1">
            <TextBlock>
                Searching for item. <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DetailsCommand}">Link to details</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a Label as host and set the template based on trigger

```
    <Label>
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourEnum}" Value="something">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        Please wait
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourEnum}" Value="somethingElse">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        Searching for item. <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DetailsCommand}">Link to details</Hyperlink>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourEnum}" Value="else">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        The content has been uploaded<LineBreak />
                                        The item is not ready to use
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
```