# Load different data template in WPF datagrid column

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

Is it possible to load a different data template for a defined column in a WPF data grid?

My XAML looks like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsStarted}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsStarted, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  Command="{Binding DataContext.Checked,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The goal here is load a separate data template when the binding `IsStarted` is set to false, In other words when the visibility is set to false.

The intended purpose here is when a certain button is triggered which will set the boolean to "false" another data template will be visible on this very own column instead of the currently existing items.

As an example, the following XAML should be displayed once the boolean is set to false after the execution of the button,

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsTrue}" Text="Hello" />
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can define a `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector`. Here is an example: [TemplateSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49393199/7713750)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the `CheckBox` in the `DataTemplate` with a `ContentControl` and use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` to replace its `ContentTemplate` based on the value of the `IsStarted` parameter:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox 
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        Visibility="{Binding IsStarted}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsStarted, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.Checked,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsStarted}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Some other template" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```